# using BOOST_TYPEOF in expression

Tags: c++, boost

Can the following be done in a single line?

```
typedef BOOST_TYPEOF(generator) G;
typename G::value_type next;

typename BOOST_TYPEOF(generator)::value_type next; //does not compile
```

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `mpl::identity`

```
typename mpl::identity<BOOST_TYPEOF(generator)>::type::value_type next;
```

The macro is probably expanding to some compiler intrinsics like `__typeof__(...)` which aren't necessarily eligible to appear as nested name specifier. Even the C++0x proposed `decltype(...)` initially wasn't allowed before a `::`, but is in the FCD.

Comment: thank you again.
that does work and explanation makes sense to me